# Bluetooth is not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I'm a noob in Ubuntu. Bluetooth in my Ubuntu is not working. It was working fine in Windows but not in Ubuntu. I've searched many pages in Ubuntu forum, but none of them made bluetooth work. I think I know the problem. I'll paste it below:

```
anvesh@anvesh-Lenovo-G500:~$ sudo rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

anvesh@anvesh-Lenovo-G500:~$ lsusb; dmesg | grep -i firmware
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 105b:e065  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b3bb Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Open a terminal window with CTRL + t and copy the highlighted command `lsusb; dmesg | grep -i firmware; rfkill list all; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; uname -a; lsmod | grep bluetooth` and paste into terminal with CTRL + Shift + v and you can highlight the results from terminal with your mouse/touchpad and copy with CTRL + Shift + c    Edit your question to include these results

Comment: its too long to comment

Comment: [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/613821/edit) to add the info or you can go to paste.ubuntu.com enter the info and post the URL you get

Comment: i think i know the problem ill paste it below show me a way to solve it                     anvesh@anvesh-Lenovo-G500:~$ sudo rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Start with `rfkill unblock all`  Then I still will need results from `lsusb; dmesg | grep -i firmware`

Comment: What kernel `uname -a`  I can get this one to work

Comment: If you do `sudo update-usbids` and then `lsusb` 105b:e065 should identify as a bluetooth device now and my answer will make it work

Answer (score 3):

First we need to get some files

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/f503f6r686riiow/fw-105b_e065.hcd
echo btusb | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

If `uname -a` shows that you have a 3.13 kernel, then

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlv2prqzzptcr6f/bluetooth-trusty.tar.gz
tar -zxf bluetooth-trusty.tar.gz
cd bluetooth
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo cp ~/fw-105b_e065.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd
sudo cp ~/fw-105b_e065.hcd /lib/firmware/
sudo modprobe btusb
```

If you have a 3.16 kernel

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/uocd0xqaprm4yvi/bluetooth.utopic.tar.gz
tar -zxf bluetooth.utopic.tar.gz
cd bluetooth
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo cp ~/fw-105b_e065.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd
sudo modprobe btusb
```

If updates happens to install a new kernel that doesn't yet support the device, you will need to do the following to get it working again

```
cd bluetooth
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD clean
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

If you have a different series kernel, just add it in a comment.
If you do a `sudo update-usbids` and look at `lsusb` you should notice that device with ID 105b:e065 is identified as a Broadcom BCM43142A0 Bluetooth

Comment: it worked  !!!!!